# Displaying user avatar and name on Google maps

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

What is the best way to display users on Google maps? I need to display the avatar image (25x25px) and user name with clickable link to profile.

I keep searching in the api documentation but the markers and overlay options confuse me, what feature/option should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us what is confusing you then flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is **MarkerImage**. [This link](http://blog.mridey.com/2010/03/using-markerimage-in-maps-javascript.html) will help you.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('avatar.png', null, null, new google.maps.Point(13, 25)), // 13 stands for centering
    position: latlng
});
```

Comment: Thanks but what about printing the username next to it and opening the profile url on click?

Comment: **InfoWindow**. Try this useful tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Comment: Basically, you can't display the username. The marker will have an icon, which will be the user's avatar, and a click will open an InfoWindow which will display the avatar, the username, and possibly a link towards a profile page.

Comment: That might help, I will look into the details. Maybe it would work to show the username as an "alt/title" tooltip and open the profile url on marker click.

Answer (score 0):

So as Jill-Jênn Vie said above, the image can be set by `MarkerImage`;

The user name can be set as a tooltip of that marker/image, it is the "`title:`" parameter of the marker.

Then to open user profile on click add this event for "marker":

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {window.location = 'http://google.com'});
```

I would paste the full code but it is already modified to include many markers defined as array.